# Templates with constexpr function returns as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given some declarations:

```
template <class T, T t>
struct foo {};

template <class T>
constexpr T ident(T t) {
   return t;
}

constexpr int bar() {
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    foo<bool, true> a;
    foo<int, bar()> b;
    foo<int, ident(0)> c;
    foo<int (*)(), bar> d;

    foo<int(*)(), ident(&bar)> e; // not accepted (gcc 4.7.2 crashes here, even)

    return 0;
}
```

Aside:  Interestingly enough, this caused a segfault on gcc 4.7.2.  I had to run it through my svn build of a 4.8.0 snapshot to even get an error message ("must be address of function with external linkage")...

Why are the first OK, and the last disallowed  - isn't this constexpr like cases a-d?  It seems like the compiler is perfectly capable of determining which function `ident(&bar)` is talking about, since it can do it for other types.

Comment: What's the error message? And what's `baz`?

Comment: Ah. Next time, just give us the minimal reproducing test case. And take your bug reports to the GCC bug tracker, will you? This is an ICE. **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/2E1cwt$2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2E1cwt$2)**

Comment: For me, G++ 4.7 gives: "`ident<int (*)()>(baz)` is not a valid template argument for type `int (*)()`; it must be the address of a function with external linkage".

Comment: @sftrabbit I fixed the sample. It ICEs. Closing as not a real question

Comment: @sehe I get the same error with the code you gave (just replace `baz` with `bar`). The only thing I did differently was create a function called `baz`. I get an error, not an ICE.

Comment: Gut instinct tells me that what you're trying is similar to the problem solved by `std::forward`: something about `&bar` changes on its way through `ident`.

Comment: @Robert Mason: I just realized, perhaps you ***meant*** to ask about the errors you get with clang? In that case, why don't you _show_ those errors? We're on a wild goose chase here, I'm not going to do it for you.

Comment: I didn't mean about the errors.  I *meant* to ask *why* this isn't allowed by the standard.  I should be more clear next time.

Comment: @sftrabit: Baz was a typo as I was minimizing my test case - it should be bar.  And that's what I got with 4.8.0.  4.7.2 ICEs for me.  This tells me that they've already fixed the bug.  I was just pointing that it ICE'd as it was interesting.  I didn't mean for everybody to pounce on it and think I don't know how to use a bug tracker...

Comment: @sehe: I put cases a-d as a *comparison* to case e, to **show why it wasn't congruent that it was disallowed**.  I would appreciate if you reverted your edit.

Comment: @RobertMason I did my best to reflect what you appear to be asking. I also reverted my downvote. I don't see how you couldn't edit your question yourself to be a lot more specific. (Why is an actual compiler error message still not included?)

Comment: @sehe:  That was my fault - I wasn't clear.  My issue was that I wasn't worried about the actual compiler error, I'm more worried about *why* this isn't allowed in C++ as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with E is that for a non-type template parameter, of type pointer-to-function, it must be valid to take the address of it (14.3.2).  For example, `foo<int(*)(), &ident(bar)>` is not valid.  So even though the return of `ident(bar)` is a pointer to a function with valid external linkage, the expression as a whole is not valid, for a non-type template parameter.  If you had returned 0 (or nullptr) from `ident(bar)`, it would of compiled (also defined in 14.3.2).

The standard allows you to omit the & on a type of pointer to function, but it still must be valid to take the address of it.  This is why `foo<int (*)(), bar>` works, because `foo<int (*)(), &bar>` is valid.  The other function calls for B, C (and A) evaluate to integer constants, which falls into different category.

Answer (score 2):

This will be permitted from C++17 onwards; see [N4198](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html) (and the corresponding wording paper [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) that was recently voted into the C++ standard). Clang trunk accepts your code in `-std=c++1z` mode.